# Errores aleatorios con Angular, Karma y Jasmine

Tags: angular, karma

No hago mas que recibir errores aleatorios al pasar los test, el error que salta es el siguiente

```
An error was thrown in afterAll
Unhandled promise rejection: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

El comando con el que lanzo los test es el siguiente

```
"test:ci": "ng test --browsers=ChromeHeadless --code-coverage true --watch false"
```

Y me resulta raro, porque lo puedes lanzar X veces y fallar en todas, o en ninguna. Lo mismo en el CI/CD

Las versiones que tengo en `package.json` son las siguientes

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test:ci": "ng test --browsers=ChromeHeadless --code-coverage true --watch false"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "11.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "11.2.14",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "5.0.2",
    "angular-google-charts": "2.2.1",
    "crypto-js": "4.1.1",
    "export-to-csv": "0.2.1",
    "js-sha256": "0.9.0",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^7.0.2",
    "rxjs": "6.6.7",
    "sigma": "1.2.1",
    "tslib": "2.0.3",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.0",
    "zone.js": "0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.1102.19",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "4.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "4.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "4.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "4.3.1",
    "@angular/cli": "11.2.19",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "11.2.14",
    "@cypress/schematic": "^2.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "4.3.1",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.10",
    "@types/jest": "29.4.0",
    "@types/mocha": "10.0.1",
    "@types/node": "14.18.36",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.16.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.16.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "cypress": "^10.11.0",
    "cypress-file-upload": "^5.0.8",
    "cypress-localstorage-commands": "^2.2.1",
    "cypress-multi-reporters": "^1.6.1",
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "4.2.1",
    "husky": "8.0.3",
    "jasmine-axe": "1.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "4.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "7.0.0",
    "karma": "6.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage": "2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "2.0.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "2.2.5",
    "lint-staged": "13.1.0",
    "mocha": "10.2.0",
    "mochawesome": "7.1.3",
    "mochawesome-merge": "4.2.2",
    "mochawesome-report-generator": "6.2.0",
    "postcss": "8.4.18",
    "postcss-loader": "4.3.0",
    "prettier": "2.8.3",
    "prettier-eslint": "15.0.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "sonarqube-scanner": "^2.8.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.2.1",
    "ts-node": "8.3.0",
    "typescript": "4.1.6"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "fsevents": "2.3.2"
  }
}
```

Todo corriendo sobre `node 14.20.0`

¿Alguna idea de como saber de donde viene este tipo de errores tan aleatorios?

Comment: Pues imagino que será un error de tipo *race condition*, estás trabajando con dos valores asíncronos que imaginas que van a llegar en X orden y a veces si, a veces no. Los valores asíncronos es lo que tienen, que son asíncronos :) Sin saber qué test son los que fallan va a ser un poco imposible decirte nada realmente... cómo pretendes que sepamos lo que falla sin ver lo que falla? :) Tendrás que ir ejecutando tus test poco a poco varias veces hasta que veas cual falla, pero 100% seguro que es un problema de *"asincronía"* digamos. Pasa a menudo si metes varios `async()` en un mismo test

Comment: No te puedo mostrar lo que falla... por que son 800 test :) Pero bueno, con tu comentario me vale, dado que es lo que sospechaba, es tema de asincronía. Gracias.

Comment: Empieza buscando tests que tengan dos `async()` en sus `beforeEach`, o que tengan un `beforeEach()` con `async()` y uno sin él. Normalmente esas cosas acaban produciendo estos errores. Por cierto, dado que en modo headless no se puede acceder a la consola, un truquito es lanzar Karma desde la consola de angular y lanzar la suit de tests directamente desde el navegador CON LA CONSOLA ABIERTA. Suele mostrar los stackTrace de los errores y puedes ver exactamente dónde suceden!

Comment: @Benito-B gracias por el comentario. De los de beforeEach() con async y sin async tengo varios, hay que "unificarlos" en uno único con async entiendo. ¿No?

Comment: Respecto al tema de lanzar los test, los puedo lanzar con ng test y la consola abierta, a ver que sale.

Answer (score 0):

Al final, por si a alguien mas le pasa realicé los siguiente pasos.

- Puse por defecto la configuración de Karma, ajusto de nuevo poco a poco los parametros modificados
- Revisé todos los test, prestando atencion a que se testeaba (Servicio, pipe, etc) y refactorizando porque había async que no estaban bien
- Añadí import de componentes que faltaban
- Por último y muy importante al limpiar de errores la consola, descubrí que los errores que pregunto en el post venían de 3 llamadas que no se les pasaba el token y daban 401